# Keep only unique column values and sum the values from corresponding rows

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while and can't come up with a solution. And yes, I am still a pretty new R user.

So, I have a large dataset with an id-column and ten other columns which have either 0 or 1 as row values. What I want, is to get unique id rows and sum the other ten columns, so they would have a value "1" if any on the row values were 1 and "0" if all of the row values were 0.

This is an example of what I have now:

```
> df <- data.frame("id"=c("1","1","1","2","3","3"), "1"=c(1,0,0,1,0,0), "2"=c(0,1,0,1,0,0))
> df
```

And this is were I´m heading at:

```
> df <- data.frame("id"=c("1","2","3"), "1"=c(1,1,0), "2"=c(1,1,0)
> df
```

When I try the following from the dplyr-package:

```
df %>%
group_by(id)
tally()
```

The result are the unique id-rows that I want but I cant´t add the other columns in this dataframe. I tried "add_tally(1)" but it didn´t work.

I also tried the "distinct" function but there were still some duplicate id´s, since one id could have values 0 or 1 which resulted into two or more rows per one id (the rows were not 100% duplicates).

Maybe I could first do the "distinct" and get rid of the most rows and then sum the row values, so the result would be "1" or "0" in each row? But, I still haven´t been able to do this.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dplyr, one might use `summarize(across())` after `group_by()` --

```
df |>
    group_by(id) |>
    summarize(across(.fns = ~ sum(.x)))
```

if the summation is greater than 1, then perhaps pipe through

```
    mutate(across(-"id", .fns = ~ifelse(.x == 0, 0, 1)))
```

or modify `summarize(across())` as

```
    summarize(across(.fns = ~ if (sum(.x) > 0) 1 else 0)))
```

In base R, the `rowsum()` function does what you want -- for the example you give I have

```
df <- data.frame(
    "id"=c("1","1","1","2","3","3"),
    "1"=c(1,0,0,1,0,0), 
    "2"=c(0,1,0,1,0,0)
)
answer <- rowsum(df[,2:3], df$id)
```

leading to

```
> answer
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  0  0
```

It might be that this results in a matrix with values greater than 1; use `ifelse()` to test whether values are greater than 0 and replace with 1.

```
> df1 = rbind(df, df)
> answer <- rowsum(df1[,2:3], df1$id)
> answer
  X1 X2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  0  0
> answer[] <- ifelse(answer == 0, 0, 1)
> answer
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  0  0
```

Some additional work might be required to make this more robust. In particular, make sure that the `id` column is a factor

```
> df1$id <- factor(df1$id, levels = unique(df1$id))
> answer <- rowsum(df1[,2:3], df1$id)
> answer[] <- ifelse(answer == 0, 0, 1)
> cbind(id = levels(df1$id), answer)
  id X1 X2
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  1
3  3  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you Martin! I tried these and all the ID´s are on unique rows but the outcome has only zeros in each rows. It seems like all the 1´s got lost by doing these. I changed the X-colums "as.numeric" and the id-column was "as. factor". I don´t know what I´m doing wrong here.

Comment: @Elina I guess these work with the data `df` that you provided in your question? Perhaps you could edit your question to show (some of) your actual data, e.g., by copy/pasting the output of `str(df)` (of your actual data) into the question.

Comment: thank you! I managed to solve this by using the row sum when I first created an ID-vector with unique ID-rows by tally()